# Der Nebel von W. Bächler

Tags: spelling, poetry, separable

Ich lerne mit meinem Neffen das Gedicht **Der Nebel** von W. Bächler. Ich möchte ihm beibringen, wie er systematisch die Anzahl der Verse und Strophen ermitteln kann, nämlich über das Reimschema des Gedichts. Leider kann ich selbst das Reimschema des erwähnten Gedichtes nicht bestimmen. Hätte jemand Vorschläge, wie man es herausfindet?

Hier ist das Gedicht:

> Der Nebel
> Der Nebel ist unersättlich.
> Er frisst alle Bäume, die Häuser,
> die parkenden Autos,
> die Sterne, den Mond.
> Der Nebel rückt näher,
> unförmig gemästet,
> wird dicker und dicker,
> drückt gegen die Mauer,
> lockt an den Fenstern mit feuchter Zunge,
> mit graubelegter,
> frisst alles,
> frisst dich.

Es gibt eine Fassung im Internet, bei der das Wort **graubelegter** getrennt geschrieben wird: **grau belegter**. Ergibt sich dadurch ein Unterschied?

Comment: Ich verstehe leider die Frage nicht... nur soviel: Ein Gedicht muss sich nicht zwangsläufig reimen... dieses Gedicht hat beispielsweise keinen einzigen Reim... und damit auch kein Reimschema, über das man die Strophen ermitteln könnte... Ich würde sagen, es hat 12 Verse (=Zeilen), aber das ist nur eine Art von vielen, die Anzahl Verse zu bestimmen...

Comment: Ich vermute, dass es "leckt an den Fenstern mit feuchter Zunge" heißt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Rhythmus und die Betonung des Verses ändern sich, wenn man aus

> graubelegter

ein

> grau belegter

macht, und bei Gedichten sollte man das unterlassen, auch wenn die neue Rechtschreibung es nahelegt, denn es ist ein Eingriff in das künstlerische Gesamtgefüge.

Inhaltlich ergibt sich kein Unterschied, da "graubelegt" kein fixer Begriff geworden ist, wie "der *alleinstehende* Mittdreißiger" ist, der *allein stehend* befremdlich wirkt.

Comment: höchst pötisch formuliert, doll, daumen da für

Answer (score 1):

Die Zeilen eines Gedichts müssen sich nicht reimen. Vor allem bei moderneren Gedichten ist das oftmals nicht der Fall. Es muss nicht mal "richtige" Worte enthalten (z.B. [schtzngrmm von Ernst Jandl](https://www.lyrikline.org/de/gedichte/schtzngrmm-1230))

Bei dem Gedicht, das du gewählt hast, reimt sich weder hinten noch vorne etwas. Du kannst aber versuchen ein Betonungsschema in den Zeilen zu finden.

Wenn du ein Nebel-Gedicht analysieren möchtest, das sich reimt, kannst du es mit [Nebel](https://hubert.schoelnast.at/texte/text/nebel.html) (von mir, März 2003) versuchen. Klassischer Rhythmus und klassisches Reimschema, inhaltlich aber vermutlich nicht ganz so einfach zu analysieren.

Comment: doch, da reimt sich *geästet* auf *unersättlich*, zwar schwach. Dann sind dort auch noch Stabreime *dicker* zu *drückt*, *gemästet* zu *Mauer*. Ziemlich kompliziert. Es handt sich hier offensichtlich um eine Hausaufgabe und das "ich" der Frage ist eigentlich *wir* (gehen) bzw. *die Klasse (Schule) un der Fiese Oberschulrat der das aufgelegt hät

Answer (score 1):

Das Gedicht *Der Nebel* hat kein Reimschema - es gibt überhaupt keine Reime.

Die Verse von Gedichten können durchaus die Form [freier Rhythmen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freie_Rhythmen) haben. Zitat aus Wikipedia:

> Als freie Rhythmen bezeichnet man reimlose, metrisch ungebundene Verse mit beliebiger Silbenanzahl und unterschiedlich vielen Hebungen und Senkungen, die dennoch einen bestimmten Rhythmus aufweisen. Im Unterschied zur Prosa sind Korrespondenzen in der Verteilung der Hebungen erkennbar. Freie Rhythmen erscheinen in Gedichten ohne feste Strophenform, die Verse können aber dennoch in Versgruppen gegliedert sein. Bei gleicher Länge der Gruppen spricht man dann von einer Gliederung in Scheinstrophen.
> Die freien Rhythmen sind eine Erfindung [Friedrich Gottlieb Klopstocks](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Gottlieb_Klopstock). [...] Beispiele freier Rhythmen erscheinen im Werk Klopstocks erstmals in *Dem Allgegenwärtigen* (1758) und in *Frühlingsfeier* (1759).

Dass es bei *Der Nebel* tatsächlich um ein Gedicht handelt, ist an der Anordnung des Textes in Verse erkennbar, die einen Rhythmus haben, und an der poetischen Sprache, die eine spezielle Stimmung erzeugt.

Eine noch extremere Gedichtform ist das [Prosagedicht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosagedicht). Zitat aus Wikipedia:

> Ein Prosagedicht (französisch poème en prose) ist ein Gedicht in Prosa, also ohne die für gebundene Rede konstitutiven Formelemente wie Verse oder Reime. Dennoch weist es Merkmale des Gedichts wie starke Verdichtung und Rhythmisierung der Sprache und lyrische Subjektivität auf.

Comment: unfuk. Dis riemt zch sea woool

Comment: @vectory Stimmt. Habe leider übersehen, dass "unförmig" eine Variante von "Unfug" ist. Und das reimt sich ganz klar auf "Zunge". Beide Worte enthalten ja "un". Und zehn Wörter beginnen mit einem "d", die Stabreime habe ich ich nicht erkannt.

Comment: insbesondere ist der Reim ''Zunge'' - ''mit graubele[ck]ter'' wegen der künstlerischen Leistung hervorzuheben, insofer man das als Reim bezeichnen darf

Comment: @vectory Na klar reimt sich das, ohne Zunge kann der Nebel nicht unersättlich sein. Und mit diesem Wort hat "graubelegt" gleich vier (!) Buchstaben gemeinsam, wenn man mal "ä" als "ae" liest. Also ein echter *Verquerreim*.

Comment: Mein Gesicht wenn jenes Schulkind im Vortrag von "Verquerreim" erzählt  Das ist doch Zungfug von dir, oder etwa nicht? Ich meine meinen Teil dagegen bierernst.

Comment: @vectory Ich spreche mit bierfeuchter Zunge, grausig belegter.

Comment: Okay, im Interesse des Kindes: Unfug.